# What are the Xcode solution organisation best practices and guidelines?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Are there any best practices for how to organise one's solution in xcode

This is mine at the moment from the root:

- A folder for each 3rd party framework e.g. KissXML
- A folder for my unit tests
- A folder for frameworks, products and resources
- A folder for MyApp which has sub folders for model, view, controller, database, supporting files and domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mine is:

```
Main application
    Model
    Singletons
    Helper+managers
    Controllers    // I keep nibs with their respective class files
    View
    Resources
        images
        plists
        //  ... groups from other types of resources if needed
    Supporting files
Unit tests
Frameworks
```

For reusable code on iOS I use static libraries and add these as separate projects in the Xcode workspace.  Even for third-party code, if there is not a static library target, I create one.  That way, I treat third-party code the same way as I treat my own library code.  Further, then I don't have to worry about versioning of third-party code.

I've found it important to have Xcode mirror the file system organization of the code, at least up to some level.  I adopted this practice after reading [this blog post](http://akosma.com/2009/07/28/code-organization-in-xcode-projects/).  I don't do this below the levels I've listed above, though.  This helps when you share code on github, for example.  Rather than have downloaders or contributors have to dig through all of your source dumped into a single directory, it is organized into functional buckets.  I've seen some projects where the Xcode organization is OK, but every single source file in the file system is dumped into a single directory.

Answer (score 0):

Although no particular method can be devoid of disadvantages, here is what we use

1. Folder for Application core or Model. This includes sub-folders for
   any third party  libraries used and folders for specialized model
   classes. For example there would be folder for web service handling.
2. Folder for one major module which would include sub-folders for each
   screen containing class files, nibs and resources (this may include
   more sub-folders according to the need).
3. Folder for second major module and so on..

This model serves us one major purpose. Our application core contains stuff like logging, data encryption/decryption etc. So it is very unlikely to be changed for many applications that we develop. Similarly there would be some applications which would need functionality of major module one and add some other things. Therefore these three folder groups are maintained as separate repositories on the subversion.

Now when we start a new project, we create a new repository for the project and link it with the application core repository and other major module repositories according to the need. So any changes made in application core by one project team, is reflected in other projects as well. Same with other major modules. This also helps us to achieve complete modularity.

Of course there would be disadvantages to this scheme, but this scheme has suited us well for many years now :)